# Nested divs with float

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am trying to nest three divs within an outer div. problem is the nested divs are not making the outer one grow.

The CSS is as follows:

```
.page {display: block;  width: 96%;}
.page .left-content {display: inline-block; float:left; width: 15%;}
.page .middle-content {display: inline-block; float:left; width: 70%;}
.page .right-content {display: inline-block; float:left; width: 15%;}
```

The html I am looking to do:

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="left-content">...content...</div>
    <div class="middle-content">...content...</div> 
    <div class="right-content">...content...</div>
</div>
```

giving a background color to the page class shows that the page class div is not of the correct size. How do i solve this?

Comment: IE only or all browsers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The wrapper must clear the content DIVs.

```
.page {
    overflow: hidden;
    *zoom: 1; /* for ie6/7 */
}
```

No extra markup is needed. Also have a look at Aslett's clearing method: http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html

Comment: Heh, thats a pretty cool method, the method mentioned in the article.

Answer (score 2):

[**The magic clearfix**](http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html)

**The standard method of making an outer container appear to "enclose" a nested float is to place a complete "cleared" element last in the container, which has the effect of 'dragging' the lower edge of the containing box lower than the float.**

Thus the float appears to be enclosed within the container even tho it really isn't. The code for a cleared box usually looks something like this:

```
<div> <!-- float container -->

  <div style="float:left; width:30%;"><p>Some content</p></div>

  <p>Text not inside the float</p>

<div style="clear:both;"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Im not a fan of using a div to clear, a tad extra markup than just using a line break.

Comment: A line break actually adds semantic. Though not very much. :) It's a matter of taste I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I added a `clear` and made sure each content `div` had it's `margin` and `padding` zeroed

http://jsfiddle.net/c4KLc/3/

```
.page .right-content, .page .left-content, .page .middle-content 
{
    border: none;
    padding: 0; 
    margin: 0;
}

.clear { 
    clear: both; 
    line-height: 0;
}
```

If any of your floating `div`s have `padding`, `border`, or `margin` styles the floating width will be off since you're doing % `width`

Comment: for some reason this did not solve the problem i have although i see it works in your example

Answer (score 0):

Change your html to

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="left-content">...content...</div>
    <div class="middle-content">...content...</div> 
    <div class="right-content">...content...</div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```