# how does CSS float property combine when dealing with nested divs?

Tags: css, html, css-float

There have been similar questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020088/nested-divs-with-float) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335976/how-can-i-position-nested-divs-at-the-bottom-and-float-right)) but I want a more general explanation. Furthermore, I included [a jsFiddle snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/pukster/yz5KD/1/) so as to better explain what I am trying to understand.

The CSS `float` property can be used to specify how html elements (ie. `img`, `div`...) are organised. If you have something like so:

```
img.sideBySide
{
float:left;
}

<img class='sideBySide' src='1.jpg'>
<img class='sideBySide' src='2.jpg'>
<img class='sideBySide' src='3.jpg'>
```

then you get three pictures, side by side, left justified. If, on the other hand, you have something like so:

```
img.onTop
{
clear:both;
}

<img class='onTop' src='1.jpg'>
<img class='onTop' src='2.jpg'>
<img class='onTop' src='3.jpg'>
```

The pictures should be one on top of each other. But what happens if they are nested within multiple `divs` like so

```
div.a
{
float:left;
}

div.b
{
clear:both;
}

img.sideBySide
{
float:left;
}

img.onTop
{
clear:both;
}

<div class='a'>
    <div class='a'>
        <p>hello world</p>
    </div>
    <div class='b'>
        <img class='sideBySide' src='1.jpg'>
        <img class='sideBySide' src='2.jpg'>
        <img class='sideBySide' src='3.jpg'>
    </div>
    <div class='a'>
        <img class='onTop' src='1.jpg'>
        <img class='onTop' src='2.jpg'>
        <img class='onTop' src='3.jpg'>
    </div>
</div>
```

Basically, what I want to know is whether

1. The `float` of the parent container (in this case `div`) effects the child element'a `float` property
2. Whether the child `float` property affects elements outside of its parent (in this case, again, `div`)

Comment: it would be better to test it out yourself and use a debugger like in chrome, or firebug in firefox.

Comment: @Joseph great advice. just found out that the height of some of my divs is set to zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [whether] The float of the parent container (in this case div) effects the child
>   element'a float property

it will not.

> Whether the child float property affects elements outside of its
>   parent (in this case, again, div)

it will not.

Generally, when you've properly constructed everything, what is inside the container will not affect what is outside.

Also, if you float the container, that behavior is independent of what you do to the contents of the container.

In other words, the container is "self-contained".

**A side-note about your sample fiddle:**

You've not specified any widths to the `div`'s, so, by default, they will be as wide as their container.  If you set a width (and IF there's enough room in the container), then they will float side-by-side.

**Edit based on comments:**

When you float elements inside a container, they will not expand the boundaries of their container unless you add a clearing div below them.

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

I think the various jsFiddle examples in the answer below will be helpful to you...

[div not floating along the preceding div with float property set to left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946425/div-not-floating-along-the-preceding-div-with-float-property-set-to-left/7947709#7947709)

Comment: ya but I'm losing my mind here. It appears the elements inside a div affect what is floated next to the parent element, [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/pukster/J4Mab/1/). See the README I have included at the top

Comment: See my edit.  You must clear the floats inside a container if you want the container to expand to encompass them.

Comment: @thanks, i will have a look at that later today. much appreciated though